# how to create a list of list of tuples?

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have a document which is read as a list of list of tuples.
For every element in each tuple is the `(word, label)`couple.

Basically, the document is a list of sentences where each sentence is a list of tuples.

I am trying to ignore the words which have less occurrences than 10 and build a new document respecting the previous format.
For that I am using this code:

```
     i=0;
     j=0;
     dictWords=dict()
     for sentence in ldata:
       for word in sentence:
        j=j+1
        if word[0] not in dictWords:
           dictWords[word[0]]=1
           i=i+1
        else:
           dictWords[word[0]]=1+dictWords[word[0]]

    ldata=[[("the","det"),("boy","noun"),("is",'verb'),("ugly","adj")], [("I","Pronoun"), ("am","verb") ("here" ,"Place")]
    lnewdata = []

    i = 0
    for sentence in ldata:
       newSent = []
       for word in sentence:
       if dictWords[word[0]] < 10:
          newSent.append(("unk","unk"))
          #dictWords is a dictionnary containing each word's occurences
       else:
          newSent.append(word)   
          i = i + 1
lnewdata.extend(newSent)
```

My problem is that lnewdata is under become under this format:

`[["the" "det" "boy" "noun" "is" "verb" "ugly" "adj"] ["I" "noun" "am" "verb" "here" "Place" ]`

What do you suggest to solve this issue?

Comment: unclear what you are asking, the indentation is broken, and your code is not executabe because of undefined variables. Please improve if you want a chance of someone answering you question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to understand your Question i can mostly figure out the following.

1. You have a document which have number of tuples like (word,label)
2. You want to have words whose occurrence is more than 10 and create a new list.

I dont understand why are you trying to append the tuple whose occurrence is less than 10.

This is the code which i can figure out.

```
    lnewdata=[]
    i=0;
    for sentence in ldata:
       newSent=[]
       for word in sentence:
       if dictWords.count(word[0])>10:
          newSent.append((word[0],word[1]))
    lnewdata = list(newSent)
```